# Local QEventLoop in QtConcurrent mapped

Tags: c++, asynchronous, parallel-processing, qt5

I have a job queue processed with QtConcurrent mapped. One of the jobs has several existing processes (created in the main loop). I don't know which process ends first so it would be nice to have an event loop to connect to QProcess' signals. What do I have to do to run a local event loop and all signals being processed in this local event loop?

Will the following work?

```
QEventLoop loop;
for (auto proc : processes) {
    process.moveToThread(QThread::currentThread);
    connect(&process, &QProcess::stdoutready, this, &someFunction);
}
loop.exec();
```

Comment: Perhaps off topic but... your use of [`QObject::moveToThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) looks a bit suspect.  You must *push* an object from its current thread to the new thread whereas you appear to be *pulling* the object onto the current thread.